# Pure JavaScript or jQuery Calls to Azure Table Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, azure, azure-storage

I am able to use Node.js to get, post, put, and delete data from Azure Tables.

However, requirements have changed where I can't use Node.js and I need to use a pure JavaScript or jQuery solution (ex. Ajax) to perform my REST Queries against the Azure Table Endpoint.

I will likely need the proper headers, authorization, and possible SaS... but have not found any examples on the internet that are pure Ajax (not .NET but a pure JavaScript file) or pure JavaScript solution.

As an example, I can hit a non-Azure Table endpoint, such as a generic REST Table and return results, but when I set it to the Azure Table Endpoint I get the expected 403 Authorization Failure as I am not passing the Authorization in/unsure where to set that and the correct headers:

```
<div id="jsondatahere" ></div>

<script>
yourUrl = 'https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/myTable()'

function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;
}

    var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get(yourUrl));
console.log(json_obj);
console.log("this is the author name: "+json_obj.clientName);
document.getElementById("jsondatahere").innerHTML = json_obj.clientName;
</script>
```

Using my example, or jQuery Ajax, does anyone have an example of how to set the authorizations so I can get, post, put, delete?

**Update:**

I can query my table but am having issues outputting the value of a node since I am used to using JSON.

```
<div id="jsondatahere" ></div>

<!-- Browersify version of Node Azure Storage Files -->
<script src="https://one.rackspace.com/download/attachments/303335292/azure-storage.common.js"></script>
<script src="https://one.rackspace.com/download/attachments/303335292/azure-storage.table.js"></script>

<script>

var tableUri = 'https://minenotyours.table.core.windows.net';
var tableService = AzureStorage.createTableServiceWithSas(tableUri, '?sv=2016-05-31&tn=myInfo&sig=DQKSL13Z%2BF9Xp3WQaBtnEpyWADw9ggWqiwhvcE6YRXE%3D&se=2017-10-10T22%3A05%3A14Z&sp=raud');

var tableQuery = new AzureStorage.TableQuery().top(200);
tableService.queryEntities('myInfo', tableQuery, null, function(error, results, response) {
    if (error) {
        // Query entities error
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, entity; entity = results.entries[i]; i++) {
            // Deal with entity object
            console.log(entity); // Returns whole object
            console.log(entity.clientName); // Returns [object Object] > clientName
            console.log(response.body.value[0].clientName); // Returns Value as expected 
            document.getElementById("jsondatahere").innerHTML = response.body.value[0].clientName; // Outputs value to HTML
        }

    }
});
</script>
```

Using above, how can I output the XML value for entity.clientName?

Comment: CORS support looks to be there for Tables: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more/ I also just checked the interface and under "Table Service" for my Storage Account it lists CORS

Comment: Ah, well that's good to know. I'll delete the previous comment then. I was looking for how you authenticate with JS and found this library, hopefully it's of some use: https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-table.html

Comment: Yes! That is a great start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Azure Storage JavaScript Library, I have what I need working. Here is a working sample. PLEASE NOTE: As a best practice, I would generate SaS Tokens on a backend server and use the createTableServicewithSaS option. Make sure to set your CORS for Azure Tables in the Azure Portal:

```
<!-- Uses Azure Storage JavaScript Library - https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-table.html -->

<div id="jsondatahere" ></div>

<!-- Browersify version of Node Azure Storage Files -->
<script src="azure-storage.common.js"></script>
<script src="azure-storage.table.js"></script>

<script>

var tableService = AzureStorage.createTableService('mystorage', 'blahblahblahbalh==');
var tableQuery = new AzureStorage.TableQuery().top(200);
tableService.queryEntities('ClientInfo', tableQuery, null, function(error, results, response) {
    if (error) {
        // Query entities error
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, entity; entity = results.entries[i]; i++) {
            // Deal with entity object
            console.log(entity);
            console.log(entity.clientName._);
            document.getElementById("jsondatahere").innerHTML += entity.clientName._;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```